How do I use an object of a generic Java class when unclear which generic parameter is used?
I have the following problem:
I declared an interface (ResultType) and a few classes implementing it (PointResult, TimeResult, LengthResult).
Then I have a sort of generic collection for these result types:
public class ResultSet<T extends ResultType> {

    private final Class<T> type;
    private final HashMap<String, T> resultList;

    // Constructor
    public ResultSet(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
        resultList = new HashMap<>();
    }

    // add participant and result
    public void addResult(String athlete, T result) {
        resultList.put(athlete, result);
    }
    
    // return type of results
    public Class<T> getType() {
        return type;
    }
}

Now when trying to add results in another object/method, for example like this
public void enterPointResult(ResultSet<?> resultSet, String athlete, int points) {
   resultSet.addResult(athlete, new PointResult(points));
}

(Edit: The above was a somehow pathetic try at a minimum working example, here's something closer to the real deal:)
private void saveResult(ResultSet<?> resultSet) {
ResultType<?> newRes;
Class<?> type = resultSet.getType();
switch (type.getSimpleName()) {
   case "PointResult":
      newRes = new PointResult(Integer.parseInt(fieldResult.getText()));
      break;
   case "TimeResult":
      newRes = new TimeResult(Double.parseDouble(fieldResult.getText()));
      break;
   case "LengthResult":
      newRes = new LengthResult(Double.parseDouble(fieldResult.getText()));
      break;
   default:
      newRes = new PointResult(Integer.parseInt(fieldResult.getText()));
      break;
   }
resultSet.addResult(fieldAthleteName.getText(),newRes);
}

I get errors like

Incompatible Types: PointResult cannot be converted to capture#1 of ?

and I don't get it, because even if I used another result type by error, due to polymorphism and the usage of the interface there shouldn't be any problem.
I also experimented with if/else (therefore the getType method), instanceof and other things, to no avail.
However, when declaring and instantiating a new ResultSet, specifically fitting like
ResultSet<PointResult> newRes = new ResultSet<>(PointResult.class);

everything works fine.
But I need to somehow work with existing ResultSet-objects.

How do you know resultSet is not a ResultSet<TimeResult>?

Hmm.. OK, I don't know, but the interpreter should know, right?
Also - even if it were a ResultSet<TimeResult> that should not matter due to the interface.

And - I also tried checking that using instanceof. But that completely does not work.

<?> is different than <T extends ResultType>

Alright, so what should I use instead?
(<? extends ResultType> is legal, but also does not solve the problem)

There's no way to check generic types at runtime because of type erasure. You need to make sure the compiler knows what type you're working with, or you could end up with the wrong objects in your ResultSet (aka heap pollution). The error is trying to protect you from that.

So a solution would be to discard the generics here completely and extend ResultSet with respect to the various ResultTypes instead and rely on pure polymorphism then?

@Slaw No, unfortunately this method must process all ResultTypes. In my complete code it gets the value from a GUI.

You need to show enough code to let us understand the problem. The context in which you call enterPointResult is important -- what's the type of the parameter you pass as resultSet?

ResultSet<T extends ResultType> says that any particular ResultSet instance only contains one type of ResultType, but you say "I have a sort of generic collection for these result types". Do you want a single ResultSet to contain different ResultTypes?

@tgdavies I clarified the example above - and yes, a single ResultSet only contains results of a single type.

I don't understand how a ResultSet only contains instances of a single ResultType subclass, given that when you call saveResult you don't know what type it will add.

That's why I read the result type stored in the ResultSet with Class<?> type = resultSet.getType();
However, programming this already did not feel right.

You say that this method must process all result types, however, your method is literally called enterPointResult. So, it can, obviously, only apply to ResultSet<PointResult> then. Because surely it is lunacy to call:
ResultSet<TimeResult> timeResultSet = ...;
enterPointResult(timeResultSet, "Dick Fosbury", 100.0);

Yet, the signature you want ('can handle any resultset type!') says you could write that. The whole point of generics is to let the type system catch code whose very meaning is nonsense.
Thus, given that you want nonsense, you cannot use generics. Simple.
Ditch the T and allow ResultSets to take anything, have users instanceof and cast themselves silly.
That, or, fix the real error here which is that you want to be able to set a point result on a TimedResultSet - ensure that is no longer the case. Then, that method simply becomes:
public void enterPointResult(ResultSet<? super PointResult> resultSet, String athlete, int points) {
   resultSet.addResult(athlete, new PointResult(points));
}


and I don't get it, because even if I used another result type by error, due to polymorphism and the usage of the interface there shouldn't be any problem.

Not what it means.
The ? is best read as 'Do-not-know'.
So, a ResultSet<?> (which boils down to a ResultSet<? extends ResultType> given that ResultSet itself restricts its type param to be either ResultType or some subtype of that) is to be read as: "A ResultSet that tracks result of type do-not-know".
In other words, it could be a resultset that tracks points. It could be one that tracks time. It could be one that tracks height. Who knows. That's the point of the ? - this code must be valid regardless of what it is. So, the code has to be sensible for every imaginable choice. And your code is only sensible if the choice is PointResult. Hence, the compiler correctly says: Nope.
Here's a simple thing to keep in mind: a List<? extends ItDoesNotMatterWhatYouPutHere> does not have an add method at all!. There is nothing whatsoever you can pass as argument to the add method that the compiler will accept, with one academic/useless exception which is the null literal (not 'an expression that ends up being null, no, literally, null, in your code, .add(null)) and only because that is every type at the same time.
That's because List<? extends Number>, for example, is to be read as: "List of... I do not know. All I know is.. it's some unknown subtype of Number (or Number itself)". So, it could be a list of integers. It could be a list of doubles. We don't know. And which value is sensible regardless of what it is? nothing. Nothing is both an int and a double.

Also worth reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java

I added a more fitting example above.
But... I think I get the idea... so the restriction I pose upon the ResultSet class by restricting its parameter (class ResultSet<T extends ResultType>) gets "lost" anywhere outside of the class itself?
Unless the compiler explicitly knows it's dealing - for example - with a ResultSet<PointResult>?

It's not lost at all, the compiler knows that T is either ResultType or PointResult or FooResult or any other result. But given that it can be any of those, your code must make sense for all possible choices. And your code doesn't.
